# Pandas currency conversion

Tags: python, pandas

I am having trouble with the below piece of code. My system runs out of memory once it starts executing the 3rd line below . I am trying to convert amounts into USD based on columns 'M/D' which indicate the if I need to Multiply or divide the 'LDIVND' amount with 'Rate' . 'USDEQ' is the new column i am trying to create and store the converted amount.

Any assistance is appreciated.

```
t['M/D']=t['M/D'].astype(str)

t.loc[:,['LDIVND','Rate']]=t.loc[:,['LDIVND','Rate']].apply(pd.to_numeric)

t['USDEQ'] = t['M/D'].apply(
    lambda x: t['LDIVND']/t['Rate'] if x =='D' else t['LDIVND']*t['Rate'] )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
t[['LDIVND','Rate']]=t[['LDIVND','Rate']].apply(pd.to_numeric)
t['USDEQ'] = np.where(t['M/D'].astype(str) =='D', 
                      t['LDIVND']/t['Rate'], 
                      t['LDIVND']*t['Rate'])
```